# Access Wordpress ajax on external host

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building this HTML/JS app to turn into mobile with Phonegap that is based on my wordpress site (using its database, users, etc.).
So right now I have an index.html with a functions.js that tries to access a function created on my wordpress like

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checking_email', 'checking_email');
```

what I want is to be able to access this with my JS code.
I've tried something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://myhost.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: { 'action': 'checking_email', 'email': 'email@example.com' },
    success: function(request_data) {
        console.log(request_data);
    }
});
```

and I get

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myhost.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

What can I do to access admin-ajax.php from an external host?

Comment: Are you requesting from different domain? If so this is a CORS issue. Kindly read this article for more information http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ basically your host must follow the rules for allowing different domain to access it's resources.

Comment: @VictorSoto it's not about the host...it simply involves headers in the server script

Comment: @VictorSoto Thanks for the info, but as charlietfl said, I just had to change the access control on the PHP script.

Comment: i meant his host being the server :D

Answer (score 1):

So, after testing a bit more I found that it was actually a pretty silly fix.
By changing the header on the server's script it allowed access to it from a different host.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // for any host
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myhost.com'); // specific host
```